# I have a Google Apps account using a co.cc domain. Co.cc have shut down (and deleted all domains) and I caanot recieve email. What do?

Tags: email, g-suite, mx-record, domain-name

I have a co.cc domain (it was a service that let you register a *.co.cc subdomain for your own use) that I linked with Google Apps. This was so I could have an email address like xxx@yyy.co.cc. Co.cc have recently shut themselves down with no prior warning and deleted all registered subdomains. I realised that I had not received any new email for a week which is what prompted me to investigate and find this news out.

Obviously I need a new email address but the problem is with all the various sites and services that have my co.cc email - I'm going to have to remember every site that I'm registered on and update my email to a new one. My question is is there anything I can do about emails being sent to me right now? They're being sent to a domain that does not exist but is there anything I can do to try catch them out of the ether?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing you can do. Any email sent to your address is going to bounce, because the [nameservers for the second-level domain are offline](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/12/11/15/2215256/free-registrar-cocc-goes-the-way-of-the-dodo) (and have been for over a week).

I would suggest you register a real domain name with a reputable registrar this time around.